# How should I redirect users in a formmail script?

Tags: perl, forms, webforms, cgi, formmail

So I'm using a basic formmail script. Within the script I'm using a redirect variable. The value of the redirect is something like:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/NewOLS_GCUK_EN/bling.aspx?BC=GCUK&IBC=CSEE&SIBC=CSEE
```

When the redirect action happens however, the URL appears in the browser as:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/NewOLS_GCUK_EN/bling.aspx?BC=GCUK&amp;IBC=CSEE&amp;SIBC=CSEE
```

You can see the `&` characters are replaced with `&amp;`

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Elliot Where is this redirect URL specified? If it is in a "hidden" input field in the HTML source, stop using that script immediately and consider putting the server on which it was hosted in an acid bath ;-) It is that dangerous to your users (and to you).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit the script with a string substitution:

```
$myRedirectURL =~ s/\&amp;/\&/g;
```

Or perhaps look in the script where the opposite substitution is taking place, and comment out that step.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Entities)'s decode_entities could decode this for you:

```
$redirect_target = decode_entities($redirect_target);
```

But passing the destination URL as HTTP argument (e.g. hidden form field) is dangerous (as @Sinan Ünür already said in the comments). Better store the target URL within your script and pass a selector from the form:

```
if ($selector eq 'home') { $target_url = 'http://www.foo.bar/'; }
elsif ($selector eq 'bling') { $target_url = 'http://www.foo.bar/NewOLS_GCUK_EN/bling.aspx'; }
else {
    $target_url = 'http://www.foo.bar/default.html'; # Fallback/default value
}
```

Using a Hash would be shorter:

```
my %targets = {
    home  => 'http://www.foo.bar/',
    bling => '/NewOLS_GCUK_EN/bling.aspx',
};
$target_url = $targets{$selector} || '/default_feedback_thanks.html';
```